# ICSharpCode.TextEditor Vertical Scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar, icsharpcode

Is it possible to configure vertical scrolling in ICSharpCode.TextEditor such that by default no vertical scrollbar is visible. And that only when someone types a lot of lines (beyond current height of this control) that a vertical scrollbar appears automatically. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

**Its easy to add the function yourself:**

1) Goto the namespace `ICSharpCode.TextEditor` and open the `TextAreaControl` class. The file location is: C:...\ICSharpCode.TextEditor\Project\Src\Gui\TextAreaControl.cs

2) Add a method to set the visibility of the Horizontal or Vertical scrollbar:

```
public void ShowScrollBars(Orientation orientation,bool isVisible)
{
    if (orientation == Orientation.Vertical)
    {
        vScrollBar.Visible = isVisible;
    }
    else
    {
        hScrollBar.Visible = isVisible;
    }
}
```

3) In the project with the TextEditor, this is how you call the `ShowScrollBars()` method:

```
editor.ActiveTextAreaControl.ShowScrollBars(Orientation.Vertical,false);
```

---

This code does the trick to show the vertical scrollbar based on the number of text lines:

```
public TextEditorForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddNewTextEditor("New file");
    SetSyntaxHighlighting("Mathematica");    
    editor.ActiveTextAreaControl.TextEditorProperties.IndentationSize = 0;
    editor.ActiveTextAreaControl.ShowScrollBars(Orientation.Vertical,false);
    editor.TextChanged += new EventHandler(editor_TextChanged);
}

void editor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    bool isVisible = (editor.ActiveTextAreaControl.GetTotalNumberOfLines > editor.ActiveTextAreaControl.TextArea.TextView.VisibleLineCount);
    editor.ActiveTextAreaControl.ShowScrollBars(Orientation.Vertical, isVisible);               
}
```

In the TextAreaControl:

```
public int GetTotalNumberOfLines()
{
    return this.Document.TotalNumberOfLines;
}
```

ps I'm using this [Code Project ICSharpCode-TextEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor) project.

Comment: Is it also possible to hide the Horizontal ScrollBar ? I checked the code and api-calls, but I cannot find it.

Comment: I haven't got the code open in front of me, though you should be able to set the `Orientation.Vertical` to `Orientation.Horizontal`

Comment: thanks, yes I know but I asked the wrong question, I wanted to know if there is a way to determine the total number of columns / max characters on a line to see if it's possible to automatically hide the HScrollBar based on that logic.