# Vertical scroll Scintilla Textbox during Text Changed event

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, scintilla

Setting a Scintilla.Net textbox with a string and scrolling to last line doesn't work.

This Q & A [How make autoscroll in Scintilla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898722/how-make-autoscroll-in-scintilla) has the answer but it wont work **at the same time as setting the text**.

Bare bones repro:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = RandomString(400);
    scintilla1.Text = s + " " + s + " " + s + " " + s + " " + s;
    scintilla1.Scrolling.ScrollBy(0, 10000);    //<-doesn't work (but does work eg in a Button2_click)
}

private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
private string RandomString(int size)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
        builder.Append(ch);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Does anyone know how to scroll vertically down to end line after setting the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try to put Refresh() after adding the text;

> scintilla1.Text = s + " " + s + " " + s + " " + s + " " + s;  
>   scintilla1.Refresh();

for this case i found out that you will need to Refresh() twice depend on the length of the string you put on the textbox.

Comment: Seriously, I'll give this a go now. AND it worked, thanks Hendrik - `YOU'LL WILL BE A C# MVP SOON!` hehe

Comment: Thanks Mate. I still need a lot to learn, you guys are awesome for providing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering in the end I ditched Scintilla in favor of [ICSharpCode.TextEditor](https://github.com/KindDragon/ICSharpCode.TextEditor). <- This one was a little unstable so I used the [Digitalrune version of the ICsharp.TextEditor](http://www.digitalrune.com/Downloads/DigitalRuneTextEditorControl.aspx)

I found [enhancing the ICSharpCode.TextEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476014/icsharpcode-texteditor-veritical-scrolling/16259271#16259271) was trivial compared with Scintilla.

Another huge benefit of ICSharpCode.TextEditor is that allows you to customize/build your own Syntax Highlighting, eg: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Syntax-highlighting