# ScintillaNet Calltip events not fired

Tags: c#, scintilla

I'm using the ScintillaNet control to make an editor for a proprietary language my workplace uses.

I am attempting to implement the CallTip functionality but for some reason the DwellStart event is not being called. I could not locate any flags that needed to be set and (as per the norm) there was no documentation to be found.

I implemented the event handler via the designer so the code is auto generated.

Has anyone implemented CallTip from scratch and knows what has gone wrong?

Comment: It'll probably be something really [silly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16291530/495455). Or could be a [bug](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/workitem/32552). Suggest you report this issue to http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/ for wider visibility. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did more experimentation and I found out that I had to (via the NativeInterface) set the Dwell time to a value larger than zero to enable it.

I could not find any way to do this via the wrapper itself.

```
scintilla1.NativeInterface.SetMouseDwellTime(3000);
```

(uses milliseconds)